# Let $d=(m,n)$. Prove: $φ (mn) = φ (m) φ (n)\frac{d}{φ (d)}$

Tags: number-theory, totient-function

Let $d=(m,n)$. Prove: $$φ (mn) = φ (m) φ (n)\frac{d}{φ (d)}$$
Can anyone help me with this proof?

Comment: Do you know a nice formula for $\dfrac{\varphi(k)}{k}$?

Comment: $\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\varphi(k)}{k} = \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\mu(k)}{k}\left\lfloor\frac{n}{k}\right\rfloor=\frac6{\pi^2}n+O\left((\log n)^{2/3}(\log\log n)^{4/3}\right) $ @DanielFischer

Comment: I meant for one term, not for the sum. Can you compute $\varphi(k)$ from the prime factorisation of $k$?

Comment: Do u mean this $\varphi(k) =k \prod_{p\mid k} \left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)$ ? @DanielFischer

Comment: Exactly that. Now use that for $k \in \{m,n,mn,d\}$ and look sharp.

Comment: @DanielFischer, please make it into an answer, so that I can upvote it. It's really inclusion-exclusion on $\varphi(x)/x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the fact that phi-function is multiplicative.

If a prime $p^{\alpha-1}||m$ and $p$ does not divide $n$ then it contributes $p^{\alpha-1}(p-1)$ to the left hand side. Also its obvious that it will "create" a factor of $p^{\alpha-1}(p-1)$ on the right hand side.

If a prime $p^{\alpha-1}||n$ and $p$ does not divide $m$ then it contributes $p^{\alpha-1}(p-1)$ to the left hand side. Also its obvious that it will "create" a factor of $p^{\alpha-1}(p-1)$ on the right hand side.

If a prime $q$ such that $q^{r}||m$ and $q^{s}||n$ then it contributes a factor $q^{r+s-1}(q-1)$ on the left and side. On the right hand side the $q$ will contribute a factor of $\frac{q^{r-1}(q-1)q^{s-1}(q-1)q^{min(m,n)}}{q^{min(m,n)-1}(q-1)}=q^{r+s-1}(q-1)$.

So, we are done.

We can rigorise this using canonical factorisation representation of the $m$ and $n$.